# Variant-like types: Why a vtable?

Tags: c++, switch-statement, variant, vtable

Variant-like types are often implemented by simulating Vtables, see e.g.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uii2AfiMA0o

Now, as an alternative, one could simply use a `switch` statement.

Question: Is there any reason for preferring a vtable to a switch statement other than the fact that a switch statement becomes difficult if `variant` is supposed to be a template, i.e. if the number of possible types is unknown?

Differently stated: Is there any reason for doing the following rather than using a switch statement in the `apply` function?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

enum TypeTag { typeInt = 0, typeDouble = 1, typeChar = 2 };

struct Variant {
    TypeTag tag;
    union { int i; double d; char c; };
};

template <class F>
void apply (Variant const & v, F f) {
    struct Helper {
        static void callInt (Variant const & v, F f) { f.callInt (v.i); }
        static void callDouble (Variant const & v, F f) { f.callDouble (v.d); }
        static void callChar (Variant const & v, F f) { f.callChar (v.c); }
    };
    using hp = void (*) (Variant const & v, F f);
    static constexpr hp vtable [3] = {
        &Helper::callInt, &Helper::callDouble, &Helper::callChar
    };  
    (vtable [v.tag]) (v, f);
}


int main() {
    struct {
        void callInt (int) const { std::cout << "Int\n"; }
        void callDouble (double) const { std::cout << "Double\n"; }
        void callChar (char) const { std::cout << "Char\n"; }
    } multifunction;
    Variant v;
    v.tag = typeDouble; v.d = 2.0;
    apply (v, multifunction);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> Differently stated: Is there any reason for doing the following rather than using a switch statement in the apply function?

I don't see that there will be much difference in terms of what the assembly will look like (broadly) for the `apply` function with either approach. In both cases you are essentially going to have a jump table based on the value of `v.tag`, and immediately call the corresponding function and then return.

I would assume that the switch version will be slightly more transparent to the compiler because it wouldn't involve indirection through function pointers. So the switch version might end up being faster in the end for that reason.

The main reason that I can see to favor the vtable approach is that, if for instance you wanted to make a template variant class based on C++11 variadic templates, it's probably easier to implement the vtable approach, because I think it would be hard to synthesize a switch statement using templates. (At least, I don't know how I would do that, after thinking about it for a little bit.)

Comment: I've edited the code and fixed the `typeChar=3` bug.

Comment: Meanwile, in 2017, dynamic->static dispatch libraries are available, like e.g. (https://github.com/jacquelinekay/petra)